# How to autoset dialog height depending on childrens height?

Tags: java, swt, composite

I have a dialog which can be called with more or less text. For now, I'm setting the height of the dialog statically, setting 200 of height.

```
shell.setSize(450, 200);
```

The problem is that when I pass a very small text to the dialog, the content is being displayed with a lot of empty space, and when I pass a long text to the dialog, the height is not enought.

In Android, this is very simple, you can set WRAP_CONTENT to the height of a layout, and then, it wraps to the height of their childrens.

How can that be done here in SWT?

This is my Dialog:

```
public class ConfirmDialog extends Dialog {
    protected boolean[] result;
    protected Shell shell;
    private String message;
    private String checkboxMessage;
    private Button btnCheckButton;

    /**
     * Create the dialog.
     * @param parent
     * @param style
     */
    public ConfirmDialog(Shell parent, int style, String message, String checkboxMessage) {
        super(parent, style);
        setText("Confirmación");
        this.message = message;
        this.checkboxMessage = checkboxMessage;
    }

    /**
     * Open the dialog.
     * @return the result
     */
    public boolean[] open() {
        createContents();

        result = new boolean[2];

        Rectangle parentSize = getParent().getBounds();
        Rectangle shellSize = shell.getBounds();
        int x = parentSize.x + (parentSize.width - shellSize.width) / 2;
        int y = (int) (parentSize.y + (parentSize.height - shellSize.height) / 3.5);
        shell.setLocation(new Point(x, y));
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        Composite contentComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        contentComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
        contentComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true, 1, 1));

        Label lblText = new Label(contentComposite, SWT.WRAP | SWT.CENTER);
        lblText.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1));
        lblText.setText(message);

        if (checkboxMessage != null) {
            Composite composite_2 = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
            composite_2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
            composite_2.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true, 1, 1));

            btnCheckButton = new Button(composite_2, SWT.CHECK);
            btnCheckButton.setText(checkboxMessage);
            btnCheckButton.setSelection(true);
        }

        Composite buttonsComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        GridLayout gl_buttonsComposite = new GridLayout(2, false);
        gl_buttonsComposite.horizontalSpacing = 50;
        buttonsComposite.setLayout(gl_buttonsComposite);
        GridData gd_buttonsComposite = new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1);
        gd_buttonsComposite.heightHint = 45;
        buttonsComposite.setLayoutData(gd_buttonsComposite);

        Button acceptButton = new Button(buttonsComposite, SWT.NONE);
        GridData gd_acceptButton = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1);
        gd_acceptButton.widthHint = 75;
        acceptButton.setLayoutData(gd_acceptButton);
        acceptButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                result[0] = true;
                if (btnCheckButton != null) {
                    result[1] = btnCheckButton.getSelection();
                }
                shell.close();
            }
        });
        acceptButton.setBounds(0, 0, 75, 25);
        acceptButton.setText("Sí");

        Button cancelButton = new Button(buttonsComposite, SWT.NONE);
        GridData gd_cancelButton = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 1, 1);
        gd_cancelButton.widthHint = 75;
        cancelButton.setLayoutData(gd_cancelButton);
        cancelButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                shell.close();
            }
        });
        cancelButton.setBounds(0, 0, 75, 25);
        cancelButton.setText("No");

        shell.setDefaultButton(cancelButton);

        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        Display display = getParent().getDisplay();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the dialog.
     */
    private void createContents() {
        shell = new Shell(getParent(), getStyle());
        shell.setSize(450, 200);        
        shell.setText(getText());
    }
}
```

If I try to do shell.pack() the result is a super small square dialog with only one button visible and the cancel button not visible and the text not visible. So shell.pack() doesn't works properly and don't know why:

[image]

Comment: Look at `shell.pack()`

Comment: Is this just an SWT app or is it part of an Eclipse plug-in or RCP? The Eclipse JFace `org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog` is quite a bit simpler to use than the basic SWT `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Dialog`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `shell.setSize` just call `shell.pack()`. This sets the size to value computed by the layouts in the shell. `pack` is equivalent to

```
shell.setSize(shell.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT, true));
```

Also you are mixing layouts (`GridLayout` etc.) with `setBounds` - don't do this. The layout will override the bounds, stick to just using layouts.

`pack` should be called after `layout` when all the contents of the shell have been set up.

You can adjust the shell size based on the computed size by replacing the `pack` call with something like:

```
Point size = shell.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT, true);

if (size.x > ?????)
  size.x = ????;

shell.setSize(size);
```

but this will just truncate the dialog. You would have to use something like `ScrolledComposite` if you want to have scrolling.

To make the label wrap the text you need to specify a `widthHint` for its layout data:

```
Label lblText = new Label(contentComposite, SWT.WRAP | SWT.CENTER);

GridData data = new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 1, 1);
data.widthHint = 100;  // Maximum width here
lblText.setLayoutData(data);

lblText.setText(message);
```

Comment: I tryed it and the result is a super small square dialog with only one button visible and the cancel button not visible and the text not visible. So shell.pack() doesn't works properly and don't know why. Also I tryed removing the two setBounds calls with the same result. I attached a screenshot on the question.

Comment: Put the `pack` immediately after the `layout` call. Everything must be set up when pack is called. This works testing here.

Comment: yeah, that works! thank you very much. But now i have a small problem. I need to set a maxwidth to the dialog, because if the text is very long, the dialog has a very long width with and a very small height. How can I set a maximum width to the label or the shell?

Comment: You could use the `setSize`, `computeSize` calls instead of `pack` and check the value returned by `computeSize`

Comment: what do you mean? what to do with those values?

Comment: computeSize returns the size that has been calculated for the dialog. It is a `Point` - check the `x` value and reduce it if it is too large.

Comment: so I must use pack, but also use computeSize to set a x? It's a little confusing, Do you have a sample?

Comment: I said replace `pack` with `setSize`, `computeSize`  - see updated answer.

Comment: I tryed your code, but something works bad with the height when I do that trick. Because the height is not correct. Now the entire text is not visible. It seems that the height is cut too. :S

Comment: This code does not wrap the text on to multiple lines if it is too long, it just limits the dialog width. To get the label to wrap use `widthHint` - see update

Comment: I am not answering any more questions in comments, ask a new question.